# php and jquery, how to do an ajax call using 2 forms?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i am using this [example](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/comment-system-database-with-jquery.html#comment-form) to create a comment system. So far works great.

What i want to do is to add one more form that will insert comments in the database exactly like in that example just use another `commentajax.php`witch ill rename to `commentajax1.php` in where ill use a different sql statement.

i see the jquery POST `$(".submit").click(function() {...}` works when a doom element with `class="submit"` is activated. Will it be enough to create another jquery that is called by another class?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "commentajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#update").append(html);
$("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
$("#flash").hide();
}
});
}return false;
});
```

It do AJAX to "commentajax.php".

If you create another click event that invoke different AJAX call to different url you will be fine.